# Present storyboard ViewController from another ViewController

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have multiple UIViewControllers in my iOS App's Storyboard. I want to open one of the UIViewControllers (in the storyboard) from a different UIViewController.

I've tried the code below, but it isn't working even though I used it before iOS 5 and it worked fine.

```
- (IBAction)addNotes:(id)sender {
    NotesViewController *notesView = [[NotesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotesViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:notesView animated:YES];
}
```

How can I perform this action with iOS 5 Storyboards?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming you have storyboard, go to storyboard and give your VC an identifier (inspector), then do:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Assuming you have a xib file you want to do:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NIBNAME" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Without a xib file:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey thanks darwin,for your reply...but the xib is present in storyboard?

Comment: Misunderstood your question. Updated my answer. Do approach 1).

Comment: hey I checked with the first approach but no luck,Darwin,its crashing

Comment: What does it say? Did you enter an identifier for the viewController in SB? Be sure to do the identifier with the __UIViewController__ not the __UIView__! Did this one a bunch of times. This one's working. Is your SB called __MainStoryboard__?

Comment: SIGABRT error,I tried by adding the identifier name for viewcontroller in SB,but also not working

Comment: Then you have to provide more information. Have you #imported everything? I don't think it because of the push.

Comment: hey avtually I want to present this viewController modally and not by pushing on the navigation stack...when I tried by pishing onto navigation stack it worked,but when I tried to present it modally,it didnt worked

Comment: Hey darwin,your code works,it was my typo mistake that made it not to work,sorry for that,hey I tried by not adding the identifier name in StoryBoard,nad it worked,it means that their is no need to add the identifier name in SB?

Comment: I don't know. It sure better to do. I could imagine that if you only have __one__ VC in SB it works, but when you have more than one, like a __segue__ it crashes because the navController does not know which viewController to pick.

Comment: how do you set some target value on the destination view controller when doing this?

Comment: I would think it's more proper to do self.storyboard if it's in the same storyboard, which I would guess it is in this case.

Comment: Works great! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

**Following will work on *Swift 3.0* and above.**

> StoryBoard

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let mainViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainViewController, animated: true)
```

> .xib

```
    let viewController = UIViewController(nibName: "NibName", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

> Without .xib

```
let viewController = UIViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerIdentifier")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Update with the Swift 3.1 version

if you **haven't** embed navigation controller then

```
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")
self.present(viewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and, if you **had** embed navigation controller then

```
let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController2, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 4.2 answer for those who want this answer without navigation in modally and in swift updated versions.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *initialHelpView = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryBoard_IDentifier" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController_Identifier"];
[self presentViewController:initialHelpView animated:YES completion:nil];
```