# ViewController initialized but nothing inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm missing an obvious point on my code but I'm not able to see where.

```
TermsViewController *termsVC = [[TermsViewController alloc] init];
termsVC.signUpVC = self;
[self presentViewController:termsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the method `presentViewController` is called, I can see that the method `viewDidLoad` is called on my `TermsViewController` but there is nothing execpt a black screen.

When I had `termsVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` I can see a green screen. When I looked deeply with the debugger, I can see that my controller is initialized but my components (UITextField + UIButton) are `nil`. 
I thought that the `presentViewController` was loaded the view linked to the controller but finally not.

Here is my TermsViewController:

```
#import "TermsViewController.h"

@interface TermsViewController ()

@end

@implementation TermsViewController
@synthesize signUpVC;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Test"];
    acceptButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: I've just edited my main post. I'm using storyboards and these views are on the same one.

Comment: If you are using storyboards normally you present a new view via a segue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924052/present-storyboard-viewcontroller-from-another-viewcontroller

Comment: check (with a breakpoint or a NSLog) that your view controller initWithNibName: is called. If you initialize your view controller using "init" you will not load it from the storyboard and so your outlets will not be instantiated. That's why they are nil.

Comment: I didn't wanted to use a segue for this one (to much constraints juste for a view with a UITextView) but finally I think I don't have any other choice.

Comment: I've just added a segue as usual and it's working. But It was not what I wanted at the beginning. Now it's done I'll keep it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your view controller from the storyboard, try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<YourStoryboardFileName>" 
                                                     bundle:nil];
TermsViewController *termsVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<TermsViewController Storyboard ID>"];
termsVC.signUpVC = self;
[self presentViewController:termsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```