# IOS - Open another controller when button is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c

i started working on IOS from today itself and started working on existing project for doing some minor changes. Through interface builder i was able to add a button. Now, when that button is tapped, i want to open another controller from different storyboard.

this is my homecell.m

```
#import "HomeTableViewCell.h"
#import "HostListingsViewController.h"

@implementation HomeTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)sharetapped:(id)sender {
// here i want to be redirected to another controller
}
@end
```

this is my homecell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewHome;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelHeading;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelSubHeading;

- (IBAction)sharetapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

I searched in google and was not able to understand. so i am asking for your help here. I am using xcode8.

Comment: The easy solution is to add button target to ViewController in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" instread of UItabelViewCell. You can find the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652133/how-to-set-action-for-uibutton-in-uitableviewcell

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar the answer you have linked to is where there is a button in the table view cell. The op does not have a button in their cell

Comment: " i want to open another controller from different storyboard" Is this correct? You only stared with iOS today and yet you already have more than one storyboard in your project. Seems a bit too advance for a first day

Comment: IBAction attached to which UIControll element?

Comment: @eggs i am modifying some functionality for existing app

Comment: There's hundreds of past questions on how to do this, for example here's just a couple that can be found with 5 seconds of effort searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924052/present-storyboard-viewcontroller-from-another-viewcontroller   http://brainwashinc.com/2014/01/08/loading-ios-viewcontroller-in-code-from-a-storyboard-file/

Comment: Hema do you table view here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using tableview in your project.so you have to set button tap action like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cell.buttonname addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(navigate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-void(navigate)
{

       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainFlow" bundle: nil];
       yourViewController *abcd = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourstoryboard id"];

       [self.navigationController pushViewController:outCome animated:YES];

}
```

this code will navigate you on other screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check cell where button pressed and send some data to another controller

homecell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol HomeCellDelegate

- (void)showDataFromCell:(HomeTableViewCell *)cell;

@end

@interface HomeTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id < HomeCellDelegate > delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewHome;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelHeading;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelSubHeading;

- (IBAction)sharetapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

homecell.m

```
#import "HomeTableViewCell.h"
#import "HostListingsViewController.h"

@implementation HomeTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)sharetapped:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate showDataFromCell:self];
}

@end
```

Your Controller with TableView

```
@interface YourViewController () <HomeCellDelegate>

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...    
HomeTableViewCell *homeCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

homeCell.delegate = self;
...

- (void)showDataFromCell:(HomeTableViewCell *)cell {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
...
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourAnotherStoryboard" bundle: nil];        
yourViewController *presentController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewController"];
presentController.someDataFromCell = someDataArray[indexPath.row];
            [self presentViewController:presentController
                               animated:NO
                             completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: - (void)showDataFromCell:(HomeTableViewCell *)cell;   For this line, i am getting error "Expected a type"!!!